# Render image from gridfs on html page using flask

Tags: python, mongodb, image, flask, gridfs

I want to render an image from gridfs on my html pyge using flask.
I store the image in my mongodb using gridfs with one button and also store the ObjectId of the image in a serverside session using Flask-Session.
When I click on another button, I get the correct ObjectId of the image stored before via my session and then want to render this image from gridfs in my html page, but I don't know how to do it.

My `app.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from pymongo import MongoClient
from gridfs import GridFS
from flask_session import Session

DB = 'test-grid'
COLLECT = 'test-session'


client = MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')
db = client[DB]
fs = GridFS(db)


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16*1024*1024
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'mongodb'
app.config['SESSION_MONGODB'] = client
app.config['SESSION_MONGODB_DB'] = DB
app.config['SESSION_MONGODB_COLLECT'] = COLLECT
Session(app)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f_id = fs.put(f, filename=filename)
        session['f_id'] = f_id
        session['filename'] = filename
        return redirect('/')


@app.route('/display', methods=['GET'])
def display_file():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        f = fs.get(session['f_id'])
        image = f.read()
        return render_template("index.html", user_image=image)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My `index.html` file:

```
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
    </form>
    <form method="get" action="/display">
        <input type="submit" value="Display">
    </form>
    <img src="{{ user_image }}" alt="Show image here"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `requirements.txt` file:

```
Flask
Flask-Session
pymongo
```

But this doesn't work and I get the following output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfO1n.png)

Can someone please help me fix this? Maybe with examples I can look up.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You really don't want to embed the image data in the rendered template. Instead just include a path to an API point as a regular `img src="..."` and create that API point which simply returns the **binary** of the image just like it was a regular file. Google's rants on "page optimization" with images actually mean for **boilerplate content** ( i.e the logo's in the top right of this very page, even though these days we probably use fonts instead ) and **NOT** *every single image*. Browsers **cache** requests. Let them do it.

Comment: @NeilLunn can you please elaborate your answer a bit more. I still don't know what to do.